# SHELL: Exit the script if DIRECTORY was modified within last 10min

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to simply check:

`If` Directory was modified within the last 10min then stop the script. 
`If` Directory **was not** modified within the last 10min then Continue.

The below always returns **True**

```
if "`find "$DirName" -type d -mindepth 1 -mmin -10`"; then
    exit
fi
```

OR

```
find "$DirName" -type d -mindepth 1 -mmin -10 && exit
```

Also tried comparing `stats` and `date +%y%m%d%s`. But doesn't seem to get anywhere.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

macOS Majove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to recursively search the directory and determine if any file within the tree has been modified (which seems to be the only reason to use `find`), or do you just want something like:

```
eval "$(stat -s "$DirName")"  # Set st_mtime to the mtime of the dir
if test "$(( $(date +%s) - $st_mtime ))" -lt 600; then
    exit  # mtime less than 10 minutes ago
fi
```

Although it's probably cleaner to skip the eval and write:

```
if test "$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f %m "$DirName") ))" -lt 600; then ...
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you! Can I ask what does `-lt` stands for?

Comment: `-lt` is the boolean operator "less than"